# Automated browser does not submit form

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I'm currently making automated tests for Browserstack using Selenium and Nightwatch.js. I've encountered a problem where I'm unable to submit a login form. Either nothing happens or the page just reloads. All required login data are set using `browser.setValue('{selector}', '{value}')`. Tried this on Chrome and Firefox, but the result is the same. I am able to submit the form using JS in browser console, though.

I've tried the following methods to no avail.

```
browser.submitForm('#login-form');
browser.click('#send2');
browser.execute("document.getElementById('send2').click();");
browser.execute("document.getElementById('login-form').submit();");
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? If that makes a difference, I'm trying to automate a login form for Magento 1 site.

Much thanks.

**Edit:**
Added form HTML

```html
<form action="https://{site}/en/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form">
       <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="1CdZGL4mwA0njx3U">                   
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-text-custom required-entry validate-email form-control" id="email" name="login[username]" value="" title="Insert Email Address" placeholder="Insert Email Address">         
       </div>          
       <div class="form-group">      
        <input type="password" class="input-text-custom required-entry form-control" id="pass" name="login[password]" title="Password" placeholder="Password">               
       </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="nl_subscribe" id="nl_subscribe_existing" value="subscribe" class="form-control checkbox">
                                <label for="nl_subscribe_existing" class="text-normal-checkout"><span></span>By the way, I also want to subscribe to your newsletter*</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="nl_source" value="customer_login" class="form-control checkbox">
                                            <div class="form-group"><div class="control remember-me-box">
        <div class="input-box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="persistent_remember_me" class="checkbox" id="remember_meL0h6snrk30" title="Remember Me">
        <label for="remember_meL0h6snrk30" class="text-normal-checkout"><span></span>Remember Me</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
             <div class="forgot-password"><a href="https://{site}/en/customer/account/forgotpassword/">Forgot password?</a></div>
                            <div align="center"><button type="submit" class="button-check" name="send" id="send2" title="log in"><span><span>log in</span></span></button></div>
</form>
```

**Edit 2:**
Is it possible that this is related to configuration? I launched this test on local browser and then stopped it, so I could fill and submit the form manually, but I was not able to submit it anyway.

Comment: setValue takes two arguments, are you setting the value correctly like `browser.setValue('{locator}','#somevalue')`

Comment: My mistake while writing this post. They all do have their values set.

Comment: is it public site? if yes, please share the site URL for the desired page.

Comment: @Murthi, unfortunatelly I can't give out URL since it's a client's site and therefore it's confidential.

Comment: otherwise, give us the HTML code for the form?

Comment: @Murthi edited the post with the form HTML.

Comment: Please format the HTML

Comment: According to your HTML your submit button has the id send2, so browser.click('#send'); should be browser.click('#send2');

Comment: @QualiT my apologies, the actual script has id send2, so it's not related to that. All data (selectors, login data) is correct, as far as I know. The script runs smoothly and does not throw any errors up until that point.

Comment: Is it possible that this is related to configuration? I launched this test on local browser and then stopped it, so I could fill and submit the form manually, but I was not able to submit it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the script was fine but there was a bug in the site. For some reason, script needs to refresh the browser to be able to submit the form successfully. So, until this is fixed, I've implemented `browser.execute('location.reload();');` as a workaround.